# How can I make a conversion to an integer round up instead of down?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var t = (timer2Seconds / 10).ToString()

When timer2Seconds is 100 then t is 100
When timer2Seconds is 99 then t is 9
```

Is there a way that I can make it round up so that:

```
When timer2Seconds is 99 then t is 10
When timer2Seconds is 91 then t is 10 
When timer2Seconds is 90 then t is 9
```

Comment: Math.Ceiling(timer2Seconds / 10);

Comment: This gives me a message saying the call is ambiguous between double and decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula:

```
var d = 10;
var t = (timer2Seconds + d - 1) / d;
```

It works with integers and rounds up.